Remove backslash from string in Golang
I have a JSON file that contains a formula which I need to use to make GET-request. 
Here is how the formula looks like in JSON: 
@100-rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job=\"linux-server-1\",mode=\"idle\",cpu=\"0\"}[1m]) * 100
I need to remove backslashes from the formula to make GET-request.
Here is how I try to do it:
tag := `@100-rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job=\"linux-server-1\",mode=\"idle\",cpu=\"0\"}[1m]) * 100`
formula := strings.Trim(tag, "@")
formula = strings.ReplaceAll(formula, "\\", "")

formulaQuery := "http://%s/api/v1/query?query=%s"

url := fmt.Sprintf(formulaQuery, "host:port", formula)
resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error get-request: ", err)
    }
// parse response

The problem is that I got 400 status code because backslashes are still in the formula. Tho if I print the formula, the output does not contain any backslashes:
100-rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job="linux-server-1",mode="idle",cpu="0"}[1m]) * 100
Here is the answer from the server:
"error when executing query=\"100-rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job=\\\\\\\"linux-server-1\\\\\\\",mode=\\\\\\\"idle\\\\\\\",cpu=\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\"}[1m]) * 100\" for (time=1712043823460, step=300000): labelFilters: unexpected token \"-\"; want \",\", \"or\", \"}\"; unparsed data: \"-server-1\\\\\\\",mode=\\\\\\\"idle\\\\\\\",cpu=\\\\\\\"0\\\\\\\"}[1m]) * 100\""

So how to make formula valid removing backslashes? If the formula does not contain backslashes, the remote server where I send get-request answers with 200 status code.

Have you tested the API endpoint by sending the query without using Golang (by directly hitting the API endpoint)? Also, try the API with a formula that doesn't contain backslashes (\) and double quotes (").

You could use the net/url#QueryEscape to safely escape the string, before passing it inside an URL

@PRATHEESHPC yes. I have. I've sended requests via Postman. the server answered with 200 status code in case if there was no backslashes and with 400 status code in case with backslashes

my solution is:
tag := `@100-rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{job=\"linux-server-1\",mode=\"idle\",cpu=\"0\"}[1m]) * 100`
formula := strings.Trim(tag, "@")

formula = url.QueryEscape(formula)

formulaQuery := "http://%s/api/v1/query?query=%s"

url := fmt.Sprintf(formulaQuery, "host:port", formula)
resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error get-request: ", err)
    }
// parse response

The server answers with 200 status code after sending request in this way.
